# Ajax link as list item

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

**What I want to do** I'm building a simple UI where you can search dynamically in an array with plain Javascript. The results list are links to fetch data from a Django backend with AJAX and show the details in a modal.

**What I get** The results list from the search works fine. But if I click on the links, the AJAX function isn't triggered.

If I try the same link directly in the HTML (not generated by Javascript) it works fine and the function is called.

**Note** Don't pay attention to the Django part of the thing. I just want to know why the AJAX function is not called when I generate the link in the Javascript list.

Any clues welcome. Thanks in advance!

```js
let arr = ["anagrams-of-string-(with-duplicates)", "array-concatenation", "array-difference", "array-includes",]

function updateResult(query) {
    let resultList = document.querySelector(".result");
    resultList.innerHTML = "";

    arr.map(function(algo){
        query.split(" ").map(function (word){
            if(algo.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) != -1){
   resultList.innerHTML += `<li class="list-group-item">
                <a href="" id="${algo}" data-id="${algo}" class="artist-title show_product" style="color: black; padding-left: 0;" data-toggle="modal">${algo}test</a>
                </li>`;
                console.log("This works fine");
            }
        })
    })
}

$(function(){
            $('.show_product').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                let product_id = $(this).attr('id');
                console.log("This function is called");

                $.ajax({
                    url:'/backend/form-fill/',
                    type:'POST',
                    data: $('#form_have_product_'+product_id).serialize(),
                    success:function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        $('.show_product').trigger("reset");
                        openModal(response);
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        console.log('something went wrong here');
                    },
                });
            });
        });

        function getFormData(content_data){
          $('#categoria_producto').text(content_data.field1);
          $('#estatus_contenido').text(content_data.field2);
          $('#descripcion_brief').text(content_data.field3);
          $('#descripcion_long').text(content_data.field4);
        };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group" style="position: fixed; top: 0; z-index: 10;">
  <input oninput="updateResult(this.value)" style="font-size: 3rem; height: 15vh;" type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />
</div>

<div>
    <ul class="list-group result" style="margin-top: 15vh;"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that you are using `innerHTML +=` which wipes out any hyperlinks that might have existed and replaces them with new ones that do not have any event handlers on them because they came into existence AFTER the code that sets up the handlers has run. Use event delegation for dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.show_product').on('click', function (e) {
```

The above is selecting elements that don't yet exist in the DOM because they are created dynamically from your search. To be able to add an event listener to elements that are created dynamically, you have to change it to this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.show_product', function(e) {
```

What this says is, "The event is attached to the document, and when we click in the document, we check the target to see if it is the element we desire." A short-hand way of (basically) saying:

```js
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target == document.querySelector('.show_product')) {
    // do the thing
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Clint. It works. The strange thing is that it works only for the first item of the list.

Comment: @FranciscoGhelfi: @ScottMarcus is correct in talking about the `innerHTML +=` situation. Use a variable to build the HTML, then set the innerHTML of your element to that variable once it is fully constructed.

Answer (score 0):

You better use delegated events in a dynamic UI. See https://api.jquery.com/on/